# '+' is not a visible method of class

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make custom structure in Haskell like this:

```
data Interval = Interval Float Float 
instance Interval Float Float where
(Interval a b) + (Interval c d) = Interval (a + c) (b + d)
(Interval a b) - (Interval c d) = Interval (a - c) (b - d)
```

But everytime errors occur like:

> '+' is not a visible method of class 'Interval'

So how should I make it properly?

Comment: Why are you trying to instantiate something that isn't a type class?

Comment: Either instantiate `Num Interval` (might not be a good idea) or define your functions outside a type class instance.

Comment: What do You mean? Sorry for dumb questions in advance, because I'm pretty new to functional programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing up data type definitions and type classes.

```
data Interval = Interval Float Float
```

defines a new datatype `Interval`, but

```
instance Interval Float Float where
```

would be the attempt to create an instance of a type class `Interval`.

I'm not sure what you intended, but if you wanted to make your type `Interval` conform to the `Num` type class which offers operators like `(+)` etc. Then you would write:

```
data Interval = Interval Float Float 

instance Num Interval where
  (+) (Interval a b) (Interval c d) = Interval (a + c) (b + d)
  (-) (Interval a b) (Interval c d) = Interval (a - d) (b - c)
```

Note that you need to implement more functions for a full instance of `Num`.

Comment: Just for fun: the way the original poster defined their `(+)` and `(-)` (that is, infix) also works once your proposed fix is implemented. That is, `instance Num Interval {- your fix -} where (Interval a b) + (Interval c d) {- their syntax for defining + -} = Interval (a + c) (b + d)` works just fine. I would even leave out the parentheses on the left, writing `Interval a b + Interval c d = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

**What You Did**

```
data Interval = Interval Float Float
```

Here you are saying `Interval` is a type with one constructor (also named `Interval`) which has two unnamed fields of type `Float`.

```
instance Interval Float Float where
```

Here you are saying `Interval` is a type class (NOT A TYPE) that takes two type parameters which you have supplied as `Float`s.  This implies there is a line somewhere that reads `class Interval a b where ...`.

```
(Interval a b) + (Interval c d) = Interval (a + c) (b + d)
(Interval a b) - (Interval c d) = Interval (a - c) (b - d)
```

Here, assuming you ment to indent, you are defining two functions that are methods of the `Interval` type class (which doesn't exist) and those methods are named `+` and `-`.

**What You Might Have Intended**

I think you wanted to define a type, Interval, and you did.

I think you wanted to define addition and subtraction which are methods of the `Num` type class:

```
instance Num Interval where
    (Interval a b) + (Interval x y) = Interval (a + b) (x + y)
    ...
```